# WCF unable to load DLLImported dll

Tags: wcf, iis, unmanaged, leveldb

I have a WCF service which references LevelDB-sharp (https://github.com/meebey/leveldb-sharp) which in turn references (DllImport) leveldb.dll.

Everything runs perfectly on my development machine, but as soon as I deploy it to live, I get the error message

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Unable to load DLL 'leveldb.dll': The specified module
>   could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I've tried putting the dll in the web service directory, the bin subdirectory, system32 and also system32\inertsrv and keep getting the same error.

I've also tried hard coding a path into the DllImport calls.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

DllImport calls does not follow the normal .net probing path ,it will look through windows PAth variable paths.

Since you have already tried to put the dll to inetsrv and system32,I guess your IIS webapplication pool may be running on 32bit mode.Are you running your application pool in 32 bit mode ?

> If so, Please try and put the leveldb.dll in your syswow64 folder or
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv folder

[image: iis 32 bit]